# TCLBLEND FAILURE - Centos 6.4

Tags: java

I have been trying to use a home grown test tool and after doing an update to Centos 6.4, I am no longer able to run the tcl based tool. I am getting the following error and I have no internet access on this server. How do I solve this problem?

```
"XpUtils::iload -d /usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1 tclblend" failed:
 couldn't load file "/usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1/libtclblend.so": libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    while executing
"error "\"XpUtils::iload -d $dir tclblend\" failed:\n $errMsg""
    (procedure "loadtclblend" line 168)
    invoked from within
"loadtclblend /usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1"
    ("package ifneeded java 1.4.1" script)
    invoked from within
"package require java"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval package require $pkg"
    ("foreach" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"foreach pkg $pkgList {
   set ::${pkg}Version [eval package require $pkg]
}"
    (file "/usr/local/testtool/testtool" line 165)
```

Comment: question also on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17196580/7552)

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting, especially on sites on which your question doesn't actually belong.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message:

> couldn't load file "/usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1/libtclblend.so":
>   libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>       while executing

I'd check to make sure that the shared library libtclblend.so is still located in that location where tclblend is looking for it. You can do so with this command:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1/libtclblend.so
```

Comment: Yes, I do see the file there -

$ ls -l /usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1/libtclblend.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 62599 Jun 17 14:50 /usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1/libtclblend.so

Comment: In looking at the error message I realized that I asked you to look for the wrong file. Can you look on your box for this file instead: `libjava.so`?

Comment: I believe with this error message that you should be setting the environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that it points to where Java is installed. This variable will tell the `libtclblend.so` library where to find `libjava.so`.

Comment: It was a java issue. I installed jdk 1.7 and the issue got resolved. Thanks for your timely help. Appreciate!

Comment: Can you either accept my answer or write up your solution and accept it so that others know this question has been resolved? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to resolve the issue -

1. Install Java 1.7: `yum install java-1.7*`
2. Install ncurses packages: `yum install ncurses*`
3. Reboot the server

TCL would start working :)